# Copy some rows from one workbook to another if some condition is met using macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook. I need to some rows from one workbook and save into another if some condition is met. i have a column in sheet2 of workbook1 which is either 'true' or 'false'. I need to copy all rows from sheet1 if a 'true' is obtained in sheet2 and need to copy it to another workbook (workbook2). True or False is obtained after doing a EXACT function on a column in sheet1.

Please note that my sheet1 wont have a fixed column length.

My code :

```
Sub mySales()

Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

If Cells(i, 1) = Date And Cells(i, 2) = “Sales” Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Select
Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Open Filename:=”C:\Users\takyar\Documents\salesmaster-new.xlsx”
Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Select
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having with your code?  BTW your quotes are "smart quotes" not regular ones: don't know if that's the same in your actual VBA project.

Comment: Note: Always use `Long` instead of `Integer` especially when dealing with row counts. Excel has more rows than `Integer`can handle. Also there is no benefit in using `Integer` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do that in one shot with `AutoFilter()` method, as per following code (explanations in comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub mySales()
    With ActiveSheet ' reference "source" sheet
        With .Range("G1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))  'reference its column A:G cells from row 1 (header) down to last not empty one in column "A"
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="TRUE" ' filter referenced cells on 1st column with "TRU"E content
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)) > 1 Then
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ' copy filtered cells skipping headers
                With Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\takyar\Documents\salesmaster-new.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1") 'open wanted workbook and reference its wanted sheet
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 'paste filtered cells in referenced sheet from ist column A first empty cell after last not empty one
                    .Parent.Close True ' save and close referenced workbook
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False ' remove filters
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=CStr(Date) ' filter referenced cells on 1st column with curret date content
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="Sales" 

how to replace this to check with whether each cell in Column A is having TRUE ?

Comment: @qwww, do you mean that you don't have to match `Date` in column A anymore while you have to match: 1) `True` in column A and "Sales" in column B?

Comment: no i dont need to match date.. instead column A will have either true or false... so if it is true, then the corresponding row from sheet1 have to be copied to new workbook....

Say in sheet2 or wb1 i have column A with true or false.. if A5 is true then the corresponding row in sheet1 (A5 in sheet1) have to be copied to wb2

Comment: @qwww, and what about column "B"? You don't need it to match "Sales" anymore?

Comment: oops...sorrt..sales and date is not required... only true condition need to be checked

Comment: @qwww, see edited code. if my answer solves your question please consider marking it as accepted. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You only need to open the destination workbook once.

E.g:

```
Sub mySales()
    'use Const for fixed values
    Const WB_PATH As String = "C:\Users\takyar\Documents\salesmaster-new.xlsx"
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, shtDest As Workbook, i As Long

    Set srcSht = ActiveSheet

    For i = 2 To srcSht.Range("A" & srcSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If srcSht.Cells(i, 1) = Date And Cells(i, 2) = "Sales" Then
            'is the destination workbook already open? If not, open it
            If shtDest Is Nothing Then
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=WB_PATH)
                Set shtDest = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
            End If
            srcSht.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 7).Copy _
                     shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next i

    'save and close the destination workbook if it was opened
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then wb.Close True

End Sub
```

Comment: just to say that in `shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`, you're actually "counting" the rows number of the `ActiveSheet` and not of `shtDest`. While in general it should be taken care to explicitly reference wanted sheet. I know you know that, but may be qwww doesn't

Comment: If srcSht.Cells(i, 1) = Date And Cells(i, 2) = "Sales" Then

how to replace this to check with whether each cell in Column A is having TRUE ?

Comment: `And Cells(i, 2) = True`

Comment: @TimWilliams, or even only `And Cells(i, 2)` since we're relying on column A values being  `Boolean`